# Panning of image goes beyond container area

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am doing panning of an image canvas(with `Image` and markings on it) in silverlight as shown below. Panning is working but the image does beyond the outer border in lower and right edges over the other controls in the adjacent grid cells. I could not figure out the reason. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="gridMain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border Name="borderImage"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <StackPanel Name="spCanvasHolder" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Canvas  Name="canvasImage" Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" MouseWheel="canvasImage_MouseWheel" >
            <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Height="Auto" Name="imgMain" Stretch="None" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgMain_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="imgMain_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="imgMain_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
        .
        .
    </Grid>
</Border>


private void imgMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isLeftClicked && isPanningEnabled)
    {
        ....        
        Thickness currMargin = canvasImage.Margin;
        currMargin.Left += lLateralMove;
        currMargin.Top += lVerticalMove;
        canvasImage.Margin = currMargin;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply clipping to stop it from rendering rendering outside the control's bounds.  Take a look at [UIElement.ClipToBounds is in WPF but not Silverlight. How to simulate in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692585)

Comment: will try that. wonder how is it automatically clipped at the top and left. it just go out of bounds on right and bottom.